# Is there a clever way to not run CSS3Pie on certain versions of IE using classes?

Tags: css, css3pie

I'm trying get css3pie to NOT run in ie7 for a certain class.  I'm using the HTML5 Boilerplate to give me IE specific classes to use.  What I've been trying to do is this

```
.ie7 .classname {
 position: absolute;
 background: #000;
}
.classname {
  css3pie: stuff;
  position: relative
  background: #fff;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working, the css3pie is still getting processed.

Does anyone have any idea what else I could try to not get the css3pie fixes to run?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the DHTML behaviour version of PIE (`pie.htc`), only declare the behaviour on the elements you want.  In my case, I have a `pie` class that I add to elements that need pie, then declare my CSS like this:

```
.pie { behavior: url(pie.htc); }
```

In your case, you could do this:

```
.ie6 .pie, .ie8 .pie, .ie9 .pie { behavior: url(pie.htc); }
```

Or adjust the boilerplate conditional comments to add an `.ienot7` class in IE 6, 8 and 9:

```html
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6 ienot7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8 ienot7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9 ienot7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html class=""> <!--<![endif]-->
```

```
.ienot7 .pie { behavior: url(pie.htc); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that you had to explicitly apply css3pie to the declarations you wanted it to handle, like this:

```
.border-radius-5 {
    -webkit-border-radius : 5px;
    -moz-border-radius : 5px;
    border-radius : 5px;
    position:relative;
    behavior: url(/css/PIE.htc);
}
```

Comment: I think the `css3pie: stuff` declaration is the OP's interpretation of `behavior: url(pie.htc)`.

Answer (score 0):

Set `behavior: ''` in only IE7. For example:

```
.classname {
    behavior: url(pie.htc);
}
.ie7 .classname {
    behavior: '';
}
```

This is good because no HTML changes are needed.